# Calculate the Sales of the last 365 days per customer using Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Given this table:

[image: table]

How to calculate the Sales of the last 365 days per customer using Power Query M?

Note: the "`total`" column is the accumulated running total.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let
    Origem = PowerBI.Dataflows(null),
    #"xx" = Origem{[workspaceId="fxx"]}[Data],
    #"xx" = #"xx"{[dataflowId="xx"]}[Data],
    customerSales1 = #"xx"{[entity="customerSales"]}[Data],
    LinhasFiltradas = Table.Buffer(Table.SelectRows(customerSales1, each [Sales] <> 0)),
    #"Personalizado Adicionado" = Table.AddColumn(LinhasFiltradas, "Sales365", each (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(LinhasFiltradas , each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Date] <= i[Date] and [Date] >= Date.AddDays(i[Date] ,-365)) [Sales]))
in
    #"Personalizado Adicionado"
```

It is returning the error "Function":

[image]

Comment: Show the output from this sample data you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for a total of the past 365 days for each row, then

Add column .. custom column with formula

```
= (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type" , each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Date] <= i[Date] and [Date] >= Date.AddDays(i[Date] ,-365)) [Sales])
```

Be sure to Table.Buffer() the prior step

full sample code

```
let Source = Table.Buffer(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source ,"Last365Sales",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(Source , each [CustomerID]=i[CustomerID] and [Date] <= i[Date] and [Date] >= Date.AddDays(i[Date] ,-365)) [Sales]), type number)
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: It is returning the error "function" as per above screenshot. The 2 lines of code are the relevant ones.

Comment: You did not copy my code. You added another 'each'.  Remove the each before each (i)=>List.Sum

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the code. It is still in progress (11h54m))